# Tricks to exceed column limitations in SQL Database

Tags: sql

Hello swarm intelligence!

I have the following use case: For every movie that is requested by a user, I create a number of tags for that specific movie, derived from several sources (actors, plot etc.. ).

I will use this data for associaton mining.

The problem: If I use the movie for rows and the tags for columns, the tags will easily exceed the technical limitations of 3000 columns ( there is even more actors, and then plot keywords etc)

Is there any way, I can organize this data to then use it for (quick) association mining?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't put tags in columns. Instead create a separate table, named something like `movie_tags` with two columns, `movie_id` and `tag`. Put each tag in a separate row of that table.

This is known as "normalizing" your data. Here's a [nice walkthrough](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Example_of_a_step_by_step_normalization) with an example very similar to yours.

**Edit**: Let's say you have a catalog of movies about the Italian Mafia in New York City in the 20th century. Let's say the movies are

```
1  Godfather
2  Goodfellas
3  Godfather II
```

Then your `movie_tags` table might contain these rows.

```
1 Gangsters
2 Gangsters
3 Gangsters
1 Francis Ford Coppola
3 Francis Ford Coppola
2 Martin Scorsese
```

**Pro tip**  If you find yourself thinking about putting lots of data items with the same meaning in their own columns, you probably need to normalize the data and add appropriate tables.

Comment: Ah thank you! That makes sense, just to clarify, this would mean for example (movie_id - tag, ; seperates by row): 1- 'gangster' ; 1-'Francis Ford Coppola' ; 2 -' gangster', 2 - 'scorsese' . In other words, I have a lot of duplicates, is that correct?